# Modifying an XML node with user-provided namespace and node value

Tags: c#, xml

It has taken a while, but I have finally been able to modify an XML document based on user input for the namespace and node name:

```
string nodeName = "DefinitionName"; // this is really provided by the user
string namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Xxx.Session";  // also user-provided

XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(taskResolved.XmlPathAndFileName);
XmlElement rootElement = xmlDocument.DocumentElement;
XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("snuh", namespace);  // hard-coded prefix, grrr...

XmlNodeList xmlNodes;

xmlNodes = rootElement.SelectNodes("//snuh:" + nodeName, namespaceManager);
```

I feel like I'm doing something wrong because I have to hard-code a prefix (snuh). I could try and choose a prefix, like snuh, that I can hope will never appear in a document, but that isn't foolproof. Another option is to use a GUID for a prefix, but this just seems like a hack work-around. **Am I missing something? Is there a better way?**

The top of the XML doc looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SessionStateInfo xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" z:Id="1"
    z:Type="Xxx.SessionStateInfo"
    z:Assembly="Xxx.Common, Version=6.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"
    xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Xxx.Session">
      <CoaterNumber>25</CoaterNumber>
      <DefinitionName z:Id="2">TwoLineMarkerDefinition</DefinitionName>
      <EnableManualMode>true</EnableManualMode>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to simply select the first DefinitionName node.

You may write

```
XmlNode node = rootElement[nodeName, namespace];
```

and if you want the whole list:

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = rootElement.GetElementsByTagName(nodeName, namespace);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using the XPath `local-name()` and `namespace-uri()` functions?

```
string xpath = string.Format("//*[local-name()='{0}' and namespace-uri()='{1}']", nodeName, namespace);
xmlNodes = rootElement.SelectNodes(xpath);
```

Don't know if those functions are supported in `XmlDocument` though, haven't tested it.